# Splitter doesn't work until weird sequence of steps is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, splitter

Trying to get this working: https://github.com/nathancahill/Split.js

For some reason, I have to disable the css height of my container, drag the splitter a random amount, and then re-enable the height property in order for the splitter to work. Until I do that I can't move the splitter at all. Any idea why this might be or how I could simulate that effect to get it to work?

To clarify, I have a vertical splitter of two divs and initially if you try to drag the splitter, nothing happens. However, if you hit F12 in Chrome (latest version), disable the height on the container, drag it a little bit, and then re-enable the height, then it works flawlessly.

Just disabling and re-enabling the height doesn't work and so does just dragging it. It has to be dragged while the height property is disabled. It's extremely weird and took me forever to figure out this workaround. Any idea why this might be or how I can fix it?

Here are my settings on initialization:

```
Split(['#txtChatWindow', '#txtGuessWindow'], {
  "direction": 'vertical',
  "sizes": [50, 50],
  "minSize": [75, 170],
  "gutterSize": 15
});
```

Comment: can you add your HTML and CSS please?

Comment: @DanO: I don't think that'll help much because my friend and I were working on it for a while and he reproduced it on fiddle without the error. This is more of a "what part of a program could be causing this interaction error" kind of problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I'm using bootstrap tabs. It looks like the tab has to be active for it to load properly. Previously I was loading it on page load. I switched it to load when the tab becomes active for the first time and that fixed it.

I think the disabling height, then dragging the splitter, and then re-enabling the height caused it to reinitialize and fix itself if I were to guess.